# When to use AWS Lambda vs. SWF

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-swf

There is an SNS topic that I would like to listen in on and I understand that I can either use SQS with SWF to work on each event or have AWS Lambda subscribe directly to SNS to work on each event when it arrives. For each event all I plan to do is pull out certain information and store it into Elastic Search.
My question is when would I use one method versus the other? Is one better when it comes to handling errors?

Answer (score 2):

For your use case you definitely want to Lambda.

SWF is much more complicated and is designed for longer processes, with multiple steps, that may take days to complete. For SWF I generally think of use cases like a customer placing an order on a website triggering a workflow that takes the order through all the steps of the process of billing, manufacturing, packaging, shipping, etc.

Comment: That makes sense but I was also wondering about data retries, say for example my ES went down and I wasn't able to write the information to my cluster. Which would you consider the easier to back fill the events that weren't written? I was assuming the SQS due to having a dead letter queue.

Comment: There is some error retry capability in Lambda, but I'm not sure exactly how that works with SNS events, and I don't think it's documented very well. SQS would be better for error handling, like you said. SQS doesn't integrate well with Lambda though, and using SWF just to use SQS is way overkill. You could create a Lambda function that checks SQS, and trigger it periodically via a Lambda scheduled event. Another option may be to use Kinesis.

Comment: The scheduled lambda event is an interesting idea. As for kinesis have done some research but am a bit confused on how exactly to handle errors in that case as it seems it would hold up the rest of the stream if one event failed to be processed correctly

Comment: On retrying with SNS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/DeliveryPolicies.html